# Do CouchDB or MongoDB support aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, couchdb

Do CouchDB or MongoDB support aggregation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MongoDB's point of view, yes.

See: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation

Note there are limitations there (there is work being done to provide greater support for aggregrations, see [here](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-447)). Typically, you may need to use MapReduce (see Mongo docs [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce)) especially on larger resultsets.

Comment: Mongo is also going to release a new aggregation framework with more features

Answer (score 4):

CouchDB uses map/reduce for this. Aggregation happens during the reduce stage.

For general information on CouchDB's map/reduce system, aka views, see:

- http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/views.html
- http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views

And for some examples of simulating SQL-style aggregation functions and those CouchDB provides, see:

- http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/cookbook.html#aggregate
- http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Built-In_Reduce_Functions